# How to loop pop in stack in assembly language

Tags: assembly, stack

I wanted to how do we loop the pop command in stack. I currently am pushing 5 values in my stack and want to pop all of the data in stack at once. I think it has something to do in the machine instruction section. I have also attached the pop machine instruction.

[image: Pop machine Instruction]

Do i have to change this for pop looping?..for ur help the pictures of the microinstructions are also attached
[image: Microinstructions]

If u have any question or my question is unclear, please do tell me
Thanks your help

Comment: Do you want to discard the data or do a multi-register pop? In the first case, you can just add the appropriate increment to the stack pointer and you are done. Actually your architecture seems to have stack grow up so decrement, not increment.

Comment: Do u mean i need to put one more spr-- in my pop's implementation